# C++ virtual function call by value

Tags: c++

I attempt to modify the vfptr of a `Base` object to point to vtable which class `Derived` owns:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
    virtual void func() { cout << "Base::func()" << endl; }
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&);
};
Base::Base(const Base&b) {
    *((int*)(this)) = *((int*)(&b));  //modify the vfptr
}
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void func() { cout << "Derived::func()" << endl; }
};
int main() {
    Derived d;
    cout << "Derived's vtable: " << *(int*)&d << endl << endl;
    Base b = d;
    cout << "Base's vtable: " << *(int*)&b << endl << endl;

    cout << "pass by value:" << endl;
    b.func();
    cout << endl;
    Base *bp = &b;
    cout << "pass by pointer" << endl;
    bp->func();
}
```

Output in VS2017:

```
Derived's vtable: 9739088

Base's vtable: 9739088

pass by value:
Base::func()

pass by pointer
Derived::func()
```

We can see that vfptr of object `b` does point to the `Derived` vtable after modifing but still call the `Base` version `func()` by value.
I wonder if the compiler handles such value-call by static binding even if what is called is a virtual function?
Thank you so much.

Comment: The compiler probably de-virtualized the call, which is fine it if knows the precise type it's dealing with.  You could check this by examining the assembly.  And unrelated, but I hope this is just for experimentation.

Comment: Virtual calls are only made against pointers and references.  They're completely redundant for calls from an object with a static type, so the compiler bypasses the vptr completely.

Comment: Vtables are not mentioned at all in the standard and only an implementation detail. Trying to access/modify them is at best implementation-defined behaviour, and especially undefined behaviour if you do things like pretending `*this` is an `int`...

Comment: The compiler's job is to translate the observable behaviour described by the source code into machine instructions that execute that behaviour. If the described behaviour has no need for dynamic dispatch, the compiler can discard the machinery used for dynamic dispatch. See [the As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if the compiler handles such value-call by static binding
>
> ```
> Base b = d;
> b.func();
> ```

Yes, it does do static binding here indeed. In fact, using dynamic binding would be pointless because the dynamic type of the object is known to be the same as the static type at compile time.

Comment: Most important, the `Base b = d` did object slicing.  The `b` object is of type `Base`, not `Derived`.  Playing shenanigans with vptrs will cause nothing but trouble.